# In Spring MVC, using HQL JOIN i am getting same Data in multiple time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

Here, I am joining two tables and get it in `List<Confrenceresponse>`, But I don't know why my all the list gives only first data in mutiple time(size of list get by query).

```
  public List<ConferenceResponse> getConferenceResponse(long listId) {
    String hql = "select e.contact as contact, e.name as name, e.ueId as ueId, c.created as created from ExcelDatas e left join 
    channels c on e.contact=c.cid_num where e.ueId = "+listId;
    List<ConferenceResponse> confRe =(List<ConferenceResponse>)getSession().createNativeQuery(hql, ConferenceResponse.class).getResultList();

      for(ConferenceResponse cr:confRe) {
         System.out.println("Name "+cr.getName());
      }
    getSession().flush();
    return confRe;
}
```

> Here, if I am getting 3 join data from table I get first data repeated three times. Can any one solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HQL to the below one.
Also, HQL does not support on keyword.

```
String hql = "select e.contact as contact, e.name as name, e.ueId as ueId, c.created as created from ExcelDatas e left join 
   e.contact c where e.ueId = "+listId;
```

If you do not have relationships in entity class, you need to make cross join as follows.

```
String hql = "select e.contact as contact, e.name as name, e.ueId as ueId, c.created as created from ExcelDatas e,channels c where e.contact=c.cid_num and e.ueId = "+listId;
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, But here my both Domain/Model classes have not any type of relationship.